# 'Bad Connection Handle' in aerospike ejabberd integration

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, aerospike, erlang-driver

tried to integrate the Aerospike with Ejabberd, and after little bit of struggle and I had hit another issue which says

" DEBUG:[util_extract_common_lead_parms()]:Connection Handle is bad C(0) DEBUG:[util_extract_common_lead_parms()]:Connection Handle is bad C(32680) " I made the connection the following way,

```
-behaviour(gen_mod).
-define(CONN_NAME, 'ejabberd_aerospike_client').
init()->
  Host = "127.0.0.1", 
  Port = 3000,
 case aerospike:connect( Host, Port ) of
 {ok, C } ->
register(?CONN_NAME,C),
ok;
{error, _} = Err ->
    ?ERROR_MSG("failed to start aerospike client: ~p", [Err]),
 Err
 end.
```